# How to persist self referencing Doctrine entities?

Tags: php, postgresql, doctrine-orm, doctrine

I have two entities that reference each other and have not null constraints, and am trying to persist them with the following script:

```php
$parentEntity = new \App\Entity\ParentEntity();
$childEntity = new \App\Entity\ChildEntity();
$childEntity->setParentEntity($parentEntity);
$parentEntity->setRootChildEntity($childEntity);

$this->entityManager->persist($parentEntity);
$this->entityManager->persist($childEntity);

printf('$parentEntity->getId(): %s'.PHP_EOL, $parentEntity->getId());
printf('$childEntity->getId(): %s'.PHP_EOL, $childEntity->getId());
printf('$parentEntity->getRootChildEntity()->getId(): %s'.PHP_EOL, $parentEntity->getRootChildEntity()->getId());
printf('$childEntity->getParentEntity()->getId(): %s'.PHP_EOL, $childEntity->getParentEntity()->getId());

$this->entityManager->flush();
```

When executing the script, both entities are populated with integer IDs after being persisted (obtained by the `SELECT NEXTVAL` queries), but when flushed, instead `NULL` is used and I get a not null violation.

If I was just getting a foreign key constraint, I would understand why and I could get around it by making the constraints deferrable or bypassing them by temporarily disabling triggers.

But not so with a null violation.  Why is this happening? Without removing the not null constraint which I wish to keep, is there a way around it?

```
doctrine.DEBUG: SELECT NEXTVAL('parent_entity_id_seq') [] []
doctrine.DEBUG: SELECT NEXTVAL('child_entity_id_seq') [] []

$parentEntity->getId(): 1
$childEntity->getId(): 1
$parentEntity->getRootChildEntity()->getId(): 1
$childEntity->getParentEntity()->getId(): 1

doctrine.DEBUG: "START TRANSACTION" [] []
doctrine.DEBUG: INSERT INTO parent_entity (id, root_child_entity_id) VALUES (?, ?) {"1":1,"2":null} []
doctrine.DEBUG: "ROLLBACK" [] []
console.CRITICAL: Error thrown while running command "app:add-tenant". Message: "An exception occurred while executing a query: SQLSTATE[23502]: Not null violation: 7 ERROR:  null value in column "root_child_entity_id" of relation "parent_entity" violates not-null constraint DETAIL:  Failing row contains (1, null)." {"exception":"[object] (Doctrine\\DBAL\\Exception\\NotNullConstraintViolationException(code: 7): An exception occurred while executing a query: SQLSTATE[23502]: Not null violation: 7 ERROR:  null value in column \"root_child_entity_id\" of relation \"parent_entity\" violates not-null constraint\nDETAIL:  Failing row contains (1, null). at /srv/api/vendor/doctrine/dbal/src/Driver/API/PostgreSQL/ExceptionConverter.php:51)\n[previous exception] [object] (Doctrine\\DBAL\\Driver\\PDO\\Exception(code: 7): SQLSTATE[23502]: Not null violation: 7 ERROR:  null value in column \"root_child_entity_id\" of relation \"parent_entity\" violates not-null constraint\nDETAIL:  Failing row contains (1, null). at /srv/api/vendor/doctrine/dbal/src/Driver/PDO/Exception.php:26)\n[previous exception] [object] (PDOException(code: 23502): SQLSTATE[23502]: Not null violation: 7 ERROR:  null value in column \"root_child_entity_id\" of relation \"parent_entity\" violates not-null constraint\nDETAIL:  Failing row contains (1, null). at /srv/api/vendor/doctrine/dbal/src/Driver/PDO/Statement.php:101)","command":"app:add-tenant","message":"An exception occurred while executing a query: SQLSTATE[23502]: Not null violation: 7 ERROR:  null value in column \"root_child_entity_id\" of relation \"parent_entity\" violates not-null constraint\nDETAIL:  Failing row contains (1, null)."} []
```

My entities:

```php
<?php

namespace App\Entity;

use App\Repository\ParentEntityRepository;
use Doctrine\ORM\Mapping as ORM;

#[ORM\Entity]
class ParentEntity
{
    #[ORM\Id]
    #[ORM\GeneratedValue]
    #[ORM\Column(type: 'integer')]
    private $id;

    #[ORM\ManyToOne(targetEntity: ChildEntity::class)]
    #[ORM\JoinColumn(nullable: false)]
    private $rootChildEntity;

    public function getId(): ?int
    {
        return $this->id;
    }

    public function getRootChildEntity(): ?ChildEntity
    {
        return $this->rootChildEntity;
    }

    public function setRootChildEntity(?ChildEntity $rootChildEntity): self
    {
        $this->rootChildEntity = $rootChildEntity;

        return $this;
    }
}
```

```php
<?php

namespace App\Entity;

use App\Repository\ChildEntityRepository;
use Doctrine\ORM\Mapping as ORM;

#[ORM\Entity]
class ChildEntity
{
    #[ORM\Id]
    #[ORM\GeneratedValue]
    #[ORM\Column(type: 'integer')]
    private $id;

    #[ORM\ManyToOne(targetEntity: ParentEntity::class)]
    #[ORM\JoinColumn(nullable: false)]
    private $parentEntity;

    public function getId(): ?int
    {
        return $this->id;
    }

    public function getParentEntity(): ?ParentEntity
    {
        return $this->parentEntity;
    }

    public function setParentEntity(?ParentEntity $parentEntity): self
    {
        $this->parentEntity = $parentEntity;

        return $this;
    }
}
```

which generates the following SQL:

```
doctrine.DEBUG: CREATE SEQUENCE child_entity_id_seq INCREMENT BY 1 MINVALUE 1 START 1 [] []
doctrine.DEBUG: CREATE SEQUENCE parent_entity_id_seq INCREMENT BY 1 MINVALUE 1 START 1 [] []
doctrine.DEBUG: CREATE TABLE child_entity (id INT NOT NULL, parent_entity_id INT NOT NULL, PRIMARY KEY(id)) [] []
doctrine.DEBUG: CREATE INDEX IDX_677D8034706E52B3 ON child_entity (parent_entity_id) [] []
doctrine.DEBUG: CREATE TABLE parent_entity (id INT NOT NULL, root_child_entity_id INT NOT NULL, PRIMARY KEY(id)) [] []
doctrine.DEBUG: CREATE INDEX IDX_413B87AEE5B68E27 ON parent_entity (root_child_entity_id) [] []
doctrine.DEBUG: ALTER TABLE child_entity ADD CONSTRAINT FK_677D8034706E52B3 FOREIGN KEY (parent_entity_id) REFERENCES parent_entity (id) NOT DEFERRABLE INITIALLY IMMEDIATE [] []
doctrine.DEBUG: ALTER TABLE parent_entity ADD CONSTRAINT FK_413B87AEE5B68E27 FOREIGN KEY (root_child_entity_id) REFERENCES child_entity (id) NOT DEFERRABLE INITIALLY IMMEDIATE [] []
```

Comment: Do you really need a ManyToOne relation between the ParentEntity and ChildEntity? Currently this looks like you actually have a OneToOne relationship between the two entities because you currently can only ever have one ParentEntity and one ChildEntity that could be related to each other.

Comment: @Bl00D4NGEL  For this particular case, yes need the many to many.  My parents and children are assets (hammer), assets can contain other assets (my tools and my garage are both assets which belong to the my house root asset), and an asset could belong to more than one parent asset (hammer belongs in the my tools and my garage asset).  Regardless of why I am trying to do this, it still seems like it should be possible, no?

Comment: your case looks like a tree structure or perhaps a nested structure, a single entity with a relationship to itself and a list of its children. If that's the case, check https://github.com/doctrine-extensions/DoctrineExtensions

Answer (score 1):

Circular entities with all IDs defined as not-nullable are impossible to persist sequentionally when immediate consistency is enforced. This is by default in almost every DB vendor.

So firstly you need to defer the consistency - see http://dbadailystuff.com/deferred-constraints-in-postgresql . For PostgreSQL and Doctrine ORM specifically, this can you fixed by specifying `deferrable` option for the foreign key, see https://github.com/doctrine/dbal/blob/e839cecc812fd04ec6c39fc865302b6a322d967d/src/Platforms/PostgreSQLPlatform.php#L439 .

and secondly you need to convince Doctrine ORM to insert the parent row with the ID of the child row. I doubt there is a direct support because the 1st point is very inconsistent across DB vendors, but feel free to open a ticket at https://github.com/doctrine/orm/issues , the authors may advice you how to enforce Doctrine ORM to insert the child ID immediately at least.

Comment: Thanks mvorisek,  On my original question, I also brought up deferrable constraints as well as a more hack solution by disabling triggers (postgresql) or disabling fk (mysql).  It is the second part which has me lost and convincing Doctrine to do it.